# Homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}$ with two different topologies

Tags: general-topology

Are $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidian topology and $\mathbb{R}$ with the particular point topology, meaning $\mathcal{T}_p=\{A\subset\mathbb{R}:p\in A\}\cup \{\emptyset\}$ for a $p\in\mathbb{R}$ homeomorphic?

I think that they are, but I'm not quite sure if what I did is right, or at least it doesn't seem right to me. If you take the identity map from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself then you get a bijective map and its inverse is again itself so bijective so you get a homeomorphism between the two sets. Is this right?
Furthermore doesn't it matter that for example the set $(p+1,\infty)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidian topology, but not open in $\mathbb{R}$ with the particular point topology?

Any help is greatly appricieted

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not right. The identity map is a bijection, but it's not continuous, and neither is its inverse. Actually, $(\Bbb R,\mathcal T_p)$ is not a Hausdorff space, where was $\Bbb R$ *is* Hausdorff with respect to the Euclidean topology. Therefore, those two topological spaces are *not* homeomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed homeomorphism (the identity map) is not continuous since $\{p\}$ is open in the non-standard topology you define, but not open in the standard topology. In fact, the same argument shows that no bijection $f\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ can be homeomorphism since $\{p\}$ is open in the non-standard topology you defined, but $\{f(p)\}$ is not open in the standard topology.